# What is this muscle ? Gluteus medius or something else?

Tags: muscle, muscle-gain

I am wondering what is the muscle circled in the below picture ?

I feel like it's the **gluteus medius** muscle but I am not quite sure since it seems to go quite high in the back. Moreover some people with a strong back doesn't seem to have this muscle as developed as the first picture which seems strange.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [Gluteus Medius.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluteus_medius)

See this image, gluteus medius in green:

[image]

The glute med sits right along the posterior of the ilium wing, which you have circled in your photo. The confusion is likely just because the iliac crest is higher than you think.